# Ubuntu 15.04 + AMD,purple screen when booting after install,stuck at initramdisk

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive, lenovo-laptop, fglrx

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on a Seagate expansion drive.  I tried booting it up from [my machine](http://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-essential-g505s-59-379862-laptop-apu-quad-core-a8-8gb-1tb-dos-2-5gb-graph/p/itmdm5ukxfqvwkqf?pid=COMDM5UGX9QFNWAM), but it hangs (and I waited over 30 mins, just to be sure).

I tried using the drive from an Intel based PC, and it worked like a charm.

I then tried loading up the drivers using [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD).

I am stuck at step 3.1.6, which says to run

```
sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial.
```

This did not work from the USB installer.

How do I resolve this issue?

---

I tried using `bootrepair`, and the information it gave me is available [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11780753/).

---

Here is a screenshot of the GRUB2 configuration and boot line (click [here](https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AADSFwrrka5ESL3mU4uGBCiWiYLKmthY0Cc4bWw4sLrUEQ/12/4518711/jpeg/32x32/1/1436313600/0/2/IMG_20150626_221507386.jpg/CLfmkwIgASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygB/hm5v1Ybs3rkjjt3teoaFrYtINrbCPlPt84P2JlBj3qc?size=1600x1200&size_mode=2) for a new window link of this for full size so you can clearly see what's there):

[image]

I tried adding `nomodeset` to the grub2 screen in the the line containing Linux instead of `quiet splash` in recovery mode and upstart mode. I have tried replacing the `$linux_gfx_mode` with `nomodeset`.

In the recovery scenario, I see the message `Loading initial ramdisk`, where it then hangs. I have tried installing it on my internal hard drive as well,the results are no different. I have also updated my BIOS to [this](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g505s-notebook/downloads/DS038577),however the problem persists.

I can chroot into the installation using [this](http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/06/02/how-to-chroot-to-ubuntu-using-live-cd-to-fix-grub-rescue-prompt/),here I tried to install the amd graphics drivers but it was unable to find them.

Is it nessecary to:

1. reinstall Ubuntu 15.04
2. install an older version of Ubuntu
3. fix GRUB

Or is there something else that I should do?